# stddef.h(216, 23): typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long') dont know what the issue is?

Tags: c

So I just installed MinGW and the extensions for C/C++ on Visual Studio Code. However I cant seem to run any programs, because I get an error at the start of every program which is the title. [image showing the error message: stddef.h(216, 23): typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIHJc.png).

edit:
So I installed MinGw with everything default and choosing the packs minGW32-base and minGW32-gcc-g++, then adding the bin directory path to my %path%. Visual Studio Code I dont remember how I installed it, its a long time ago, but should have just been a default installation. I did add the extension called "C/C++". I set up the project by just making a folder and opened it in VSCode, then made a ".c" file which I then wrote my code in. Ive tested the code on a linux machine, but on my windows computer it just gets that error. I get the error when I tried to run it. /end edit.

When I click into this issue, it opens the file stddef.h and shows line 217 col 23 as the issue. I have no idea what that issue is. I saw someone else had posted about it here about 10 months ago, but no answers or solutions, so im posting it again to see if maybe someone can help?

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long fib(int n)
{
        long fibCashe[n];
        int i;

        //Om n er 0 eller 1 er nummeret 0 og 1 som definison av fibonacci nummerene så det trenger ikke utregning
        if(n == 0)
                return 0;
        if(n >= 1){
                fibCashe[0] = 0;
                if(n == 1)
                        return 1;
        }
        //Utregning af Fibonacci nummeret
        if(n >= 2){
                fibCashe[1] = 1;
                for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
                        fibCashe[i] = fibCashe[i-1] + fibCashe[i-2];
                }
                //Fil lagrings delen
                FILE * fil;
                int x;

                fil = fopen("fibonacci.txt", "w");
                for(x=0;x<=n;x++){
                        fprintf(fil,"%d, ",fibCashe[x]);
                }
                if(fil == NULL){
                        printf("Failed to write to file...\n");
                        exit(1);
                }
                fclose(fil);

                return fibCashe[n];
        }
}

int main()
{
        int usrInp;

        printf("Enter n for Fn of the Fibonacci-numbers you want to see...");
        scanf("%d",&usrInp);
        printf("You entered: %d\n",usrInp);
        printf("This gives you the fibbonacci number: %ld\n",fib(usrInp));
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail how you installed and configured both MinGW and Visual Studio Code, how you setup your project, including the source code you are trying to compile/run, etc. There is likely a mistake in how you setup your environment that someone might spot if you explain it in detail. Is that even a compilation error? What does "_get an error at the start of every program_" mean? It looks more like a diagnostics tooling error to me. Can you still compile and run the program?

Comment: typedef redefinition means that somewhere in your code (or in files included by you code) you have two statements such as `typedef long _ssize_t` (line 216 in stddef.h) and `typedef unsigned int _ssize_t`.  The interesting thing is that there is a conditional compilation guard, #ifdef __BEOS__ on line 215 which ends on line 217 `#endif /* __BEOS__ */`.  This line should not be seen by the compiler unless you are compiling for BEOS.  We need to see all of the code.  BTW: I was looking athttps://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h for my line numbers

Comment: @user17732522 So I installed MinGw with everything default and choosing the packs minGW32-base and minGW32-gcc-g++, then adding the bin directory path to my %path%. Visual Studio Code I dont remember how I installed it, its a long time ago, but should have just been a default installation. I did add the extension called "C/C++". I set up the project by just making a folder and opened it in VSCode, then made a ".c" file which I then wrote my code in. Ive tested the code on a linux machine, but on my windows computer it just gets that error. I get the error when I tried to run it.

Comment: @thurizas I added the code I had written in the post now, its my first time posting for help, so not used to all I need to send sorry

Comment: The error says "_clang-diagnostic-error_". That doesn't sound like it has anything to do with your compiler (GCC instead of Clang). It sounds like the code analysis isn't correctly configured. "_I get the error when I tried to run it._": That can't be possible. Either it is a code analysis error or a compilation error. It can't be an error that you get when running the compiled program.

Comment: @user17732522 so it was when I clicked "run" on VSCode that I got it, but it was an issue before even compiling or when trying to compile

Comment: I entered your code into a file (main.c) and compiled it with the command line, `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall main.c -o fib`.  The code compiles (with two warnings), and I was able to run the resulting executable.  However, the resulting executable did not give me what I was expecting, Asking for the fifth Fibonacci number it return 5.  The Fibonacci series is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, .... .  I would expect that the fifth Fibonacci number would have been 3.  So at this point, I would have to ask what is VSCode doing when you attempt to compile?